# what does STATUS_PENDING mean?

Tags: c, windows, operating-system, native, nt-native-api

I am not getting concept regarding NT processes as I am using native APIs.Since they are returning values like `STATUS_TIMEOUT`, `STATUS_PENDING` etc.What does `STATUS_PENDING` really mean?

My code goes like this.

```
NTSTATUS rc;
rc = NtReadFile(
                            Keybrds[iLoop].hKeyboard,
                            Keybrds[iLoop].hEvent,
                            NULL,
                            NULL,
                            &IoStatusBlock,
                            &KbData,
                            sizeof(KEYBOARD_INPUT_DATA),
                            &ByteOffset,
                            NULL
                            );
```

Here,`NtReadFile()` is returning `STATUS_PENDING`, what does that means?

Comment: Hmmmm, a program using the native APIs to read keyboard data. What might this be?

Comment: @JonathonReinhart: for example an application similar to `autochk.exe` or UltraDefrag ... just to name two completely harmless applications which would be doing just that.

Comment: @JonathonReinhart Well, i was working with “Defragmentation” application. Which was needed to be invoked during boot time. And if user wants to abort defragmentation, he needs to press ESC to abort “Defragmentation”

Answer (score 6):

It [means](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff567072(v=vs.85).aspx) the I/O operation is pending, and you should wait on the handle for its completion. It also probably means the file handle is opened in async mode; if you want synchrony you should open the handle in synchronous mode instead to avoid `STATUS_PENDING` in the first place.

Comment: Thank you.But,as i am a beginner, i dont know how to open the handle in synchronous mode to avoid STATUS_PENDING.

Comment: @sonugupta: you need to specify `FILE_SYNCHRONOUS_IO_ALERT` or `FILE_SYNCHRONOUS_IO_NONALERT` along with `SYNCHRONIZE` when you call `NtOpenFile` or `NtCreateFile`.  See here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff566424%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: Actually what i want is,user should press ESC key within 10 seconds. I have tried using FILE_SYNCHRONOUS_IO_ALERT or FILE_SYNCHRONOUS_IO_NONALERT along with SYNCHRONIZE while creating file using NtcreateFile. But at boot time,screen stucks for user input for unlimited time.

Answer (score 5):

`NtReadFile` [and `ZwReadFile`] are two versions of the same Windows Native System Services routine. As per the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff567072(v=vs.85).aspx)

> #### Return value
>
> ZwReadFile returns either STATUS_SUCCESS or the appropriate NTSTATUS error code.

Yes, `STATUS_PENDING` is a return error code. It is documented as

> 0x00000103
>   STATUS_PENDING
>   The operation that was requested is pending completion.

This message indicates that some of the I/O operation using the same handle is already pending. The handle is probably opened in asynchronous mode and thus by having the return value of `STATUS_PENDING`, the caller will wait for the completion of the ongoing operation on that handle.

In case of the file handle was opened in *async* mode, the `NtReadFile ()` will not wait itself on the handle. OTOH, for handles with *sync* mode, `NtReadFile ()` will wait [*block*] until the read operation is complete.

Now, as for details of `NTSTATUS error code` part, you can have a look at [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc704588.aspx).

Comment: But, i do not want to block read operation.I have specified some time interval say of 10 seconds and if it does not get any input till that time,some another function is called.

Comment: @sonugupta well, then, upon receiving `STATUS_PENDING` you have to keep watch on the handle itself, up to the timeout.

Comment: @sonugupta also _The caller can safely wait on the file handle only if all three of the following conditions are met:
The handle was opened for asynchronous access (that is, neither FILE_SYNCHRONOUS_IO_XXX flag was specified).
The handle is being used for only one I/O operation at a time.
ZwReadFile returned STATUS_PENDING._

Comment: Yes but, since i am waiting for multiple handles and hence i have used     **rc = NtWaitForMultipleObjects(iDest, hTempEvents, WaitAnyObject, TRUE, &TimeOut);** where hTempEvents is array of handles. The value returned by NtWaitForMultipleObjects is STATUS_PENDING.It never returns STATUS_SUCCESS.